# How to display entries corresponding to a specific $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My page will display a list of available restaurants using a `mysqli_fetch_array` within a while loop. From these I can select the restaurant  I want. After that, I'm trying to display the menu items corresponding to a given `restaurant` based on its `rest_id`.

In `index.php`, I've put the `rest_id` values retrieved from the `restaurant` table into a $_SESSION['restid'] variable. I.e.

$_SESSION['restid'] = $row['rest_id'];

However, when I use the $_SESSION variable in `viewMenu.php` to display the `menu` entries corresponding to a given `rest_id`, it will only display the entries that corresponds to the final `rest_id` in the `restaurant` table.

I do think that's because in the while loop to display the records for the `restaurant`, the $_SESSION variable will be set to the last `rest_id` value retrieved by the loop. I can think of an array, but have no clue how to implement it.

So, my question is: how do I get the specific $_SESSION value, which corresponds to the specific `rest_id` I selected so that I get only the entries based on the restaurant I actually selected?

`index.php`

```
     <?php
            //Connect to mysql db
            $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','toor');
            //select database
            mysqli_select_db($con,'eatrebs');
            //Select query
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurant";
            //Execute query
            $records = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            ?>

            <?php
                    session_start();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
            {

                echo '<tr><form action="update.php" method="post">';
                echo"<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row['rest_id']."'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type = text name = \"rname\"  value = '".$row['rest_name']."'</td>";
                echo "<td><input type = text name = \"email\"  value = '".$row['email']."'</td>";
                echo "<td><input type = text name = \"address\"  value = '".$row['address']."'</td>";
                echo'<td><input type=submit value="Update" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');">';
                echo'<td><Button btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left name=del onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');">Delete</Button>';
                echo "</form>";

                echo '<form action="Menu/viewMenu.php" method="post">';
                echo"<input type=hidden name=iid value='".$row['rest_id']."'></td>";
                $_SESSION['restid'] = $row['rest_id'];
                echo"<td><input type=submit value=\"View Menu\" name=viewMenu>";
                echo'</form></tr>';

            }





//viewMenu.php
    <?php
        session_start();
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","toor");
        mysqli_select_db($con, 'eatrebs');
        $sql = "SELECT items.* FROM items INNER JOIN restaurant ON restaurant.rest_id = items.rest_id Where items.rest_id = '{$_SESSION['restid']}' ";

        $menu = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    ?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['restid'] = $row['rest_id'];` will overwrite the value on each iteration through the loop - hence only ever appearing to store the LAST entry. Use `$_SESSION['restid'][] = $row['rest_id'];` to add to an array. Incorporate the `restid` either in the `form action` url or as a hidden field perhaps are two ways around this issue

Comment: incidentally your HTML is NOT valid - you cannot put a `form` element where you have it and then adding `td` tags here and there.... either put the form entirely within a `td` or have the entire table within a form...

Comment: in `viewMenu.php` do not try to use the session value - instead either look for the GET value in the querystring ( if you assigned the form action as viewmenu?rest_id=X ) or look for the POSTed `iid` variable

Comment: The `viewMenu` is supposed to allow me to update the Menus again using another `updateMenu.php` script. I did use $_POST [rest_id] like you described. But, when I do the update and the page redirects to the `viewMenu`, I get the `iid` unreferenced error.